Не происходит пагинация в Python, Scrapy. Почему?
Есть код:
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "card_json"
    allowed_domains = ["apple-market.ru"]
    count = 1
    while count <= 10:
        start_urls = [f"https://apple-market.ru/iphone/?page={count}"]

        def parse(self, response):
            # Извлекаем все карточки товаров из списка
            heads = response.xpath('//ul[@class="catalog-page__list"]/li')
            for head in heads:
                product_link = head.xpath('.//div[@class="product__preview"]/a/@href').get()
                # Генерируем полный URL для товара
                full_product_link = response.urljoin(product_link)

                # Отправляем запрос на страницу товара
                yield scrapy.Request(full_product_link, callback=self.parse_product)

        def parse_product(self, response):
            # Извлекаем данные о товаре более подробно
            product_data = {
                'name': response.xpath('.//h1[@class="product-review__info-title"]/text()').get().strip(),
                'price': response.xpath('//div[@class="product-review__buy-price"]/text()').get().strip(),
                'photo': response.xpath('.//img[@itemprop="contentUrl"]/@src').get(),
                'description': []
            }

            # Извлекаем каждый элемент описания и добавляем его в список.
            description_elements = response.xpath(
                '//tbody[@class="product-review__characteristics-list-container"]/tr')
            for element in description_elements:
                key = element.xpath('.//td[@class="product-review__characteristics-label"]/text()').get()
                value = element.xpath('.//td[@class="product-review__characteristics-value"]/text()').get()
                text = key + ': ' + value
                if text:
                    product_data['description'].append(text.strip())

            yield product_data
        count += 1

Данные собираются только с одной страницы не проходя по нужному количеству страниц. Если кто знает причину подскажите почему так происходит?
